# Double Click on ag-grid webelement using UFT

Tags: automation, automated-tests, ui-automation, qtp, hp-uft

We are facing an issue in automating “ag-Grid” components as its identified as webelement. We need to double click on ag-Grid object to change to webedit and then we’ll be able to set some data on the webedit field.

When we tried to double click using functions like onclick/dblclick/objectclick/fireevent, the action is successful without any error but after the completion of the event the webelement is not changed to webedit and we are unable to add any data in the field.

we are using UFT 12.0 version

Comment: Did you try to use [`DoubleClick`](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#Web/WEBPACKAGELib~WebElement.html#DoubleClick)?

Comment: Try by `Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2` and revert it back to `1` after click.

Comment: Try this if ti works:
//Create a Weblement Object.
Set oWeb = Descrtiption.create
oweb("name").value = "Name of object"

//Then click on that weblelement until it become web edit using do while 

Do 
Browser().PAge.Weblement(oWeb).click
wait 1
Loop while Browser().Page().WebEdit().Exist <> True
  
//it will click on web Element until it becomes webEdit . 
Not an optimized method but u can use if nothing works

Comment: @ManishChristian I have tried with that option but it didn't work